# Foreign key constraint sql error from entries/saveEntry when adding entry

Tags: form, saveentry

I am getting a foreign key constraint sql error when trying to add an entry through a front end form.

```
<form method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8">
  {{ getCsrfInput() }}
  <input type="hidden" name="action" value="entries/saveEntry">
  <input type="hidden" name="entryId" value="{{ entry.id }}">
  <select name="fields[vendor][]">
    {% for v in craft.entries.section('vendors') %}
      <option value="v.id">{{v.title}}</option>
    {% endfor %}
  </select>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

`vendor` is an Entries fieldtype, for unlimited entries from the `vendors` channel. Very similar code for adding a category works fine.

The error (complete with back-ticks):

> CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`metro`.`craft_relations`, CONSTRAINT `craft_relations_targetId_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`targetId`) REFERENCES `craft_elements` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE). The SQL statement executed was: INSERT INTO `craft_relations` (`fieldId`, `sourceId`, `sourceLocale`, `targetId`, `sortOrder`, `dateCreated`, `dateUpdated`, `uid`) VALUES (:row0_col0, :row0_col1, NULL, :row0_col3, :row0_col4, :row0_col5, :row0_col6, :row0_col7). Bound with :row0_col0='13', :row0_col1='39', :row0_col3='v.id', :row0_col4=1, :row0_col5='2016-02-13 08:28:03', :row0_col6='2016-02-13 08:28:03', :row0_col7='e455a06e-8f9d-4299-ad57-93577907f9a0'

Comment: Can you share the actual FK constraint error?

Comment: @BradBell added

Comment: Are there any other fields in the `vendors` channel?  Also, could you enable devMode and share the stack trace leading up to the error?

Comment: @BradBell Filed a support ticket, since you are implying this is a bug.

Comment: `since you are implying this is a bug.` - well, just trying to figure out what's going on. :) I think I see though so adding an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is this:

```
<option value="v.id">{{v.title}}</option>
```

Try changing it to:

```
<option value="{{ v.id }}">{{v.title}}</option>
```

Comment: aarg! Hope this will help someone else with a 'foreign key constraint' sql error.